# It keeps saying "Special Characters must be escaped: <" What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help making a button which uses a javascript function to redirect the user to a variety of websites. The code below keeps saying that "Special Characters must be escaped: <" when I hover over the red error notification.

I looked it up previously on StackOverflow with no avail.

```html
<button onClick="goSomewhere()">
<center>Stagger my Beliefs in the internet</center>
</button>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="goSomewhere()">`?

Comment: The code says no such thing. Is this in an editor or console you get a red error?

Comment: And you likely want `<button type="button" onclick="goSomewhere()">...</button>`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Presumably your editor is getting confused because it can't figure out how to parse the invalid HTML, so it's giving a misleading error.

Comment: I'm using Adobe DreamWeaver

Comment: Note that `<center>` [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onclick for js function invocation

```
<button onclick="goSomeWhere()"><center>Stagger my Beliefs in the internet</center></button>
```

Otherwise use Jquery or Js to bind a function to the button class name or id, to tigger on click

```
<button class="myButtonClass"><center>Stagger my Beliefs in the internet</center></button>

$(".myButtonClass").click(goSomeWhere);
```